# Create multiple VM in azure in the same subscription at the same time when another user also does the same

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have run the powershell script for creating azure VM. An error occurs "Cannot find VM current status" when another user too creates VM in the same cloudservice. How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the powershell script code you're executing, and the resulting error output. Also please clarify if this is occurring when both of you are executing operations simultaneously. We don't know the context of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Azure has two different deployment models for creating and working with resources: Resource Manager (the new one) and Classic (the old one). It is transitioning from classic to Resource Manager.

You are using Cloud Services, which exist only with the classic deployment model. One of the problem with classic is the fact that most operations on your resources cannot be paralyzed.
When you edit the state of a cloud service, it won't accept any other operations until the first one is done.

Microsoft recommends that most new deployments use the Resource Manager model.
If you can, you should consider to migrate to the new model.

Please see:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-azurerm-versus-azuresm/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-manage-vm-asm-arm/

Comment: You're assuming the two users are executing operations at the same time. That would be good for the OP to clarify, since that's  just a working assumption. It could be unrelated.

Comment: That's my understanding from "when another user too".